# Use of MD5 output for AES key

Tags: java, hash, aes, md5

i want to use MD5 hash value as an AES key. But MD5 output is in hex digits(32 four bit values). So how can i convert them to a format suitable for AES encryption(16 8 bit values). I wish to do it in java.

Comment: "But MD5 output is in hex digits" - no, it's just binary data. You may happen to currently be converting it into hex, but you certainly don't have to.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you already have the MD5 HEX String from another process/program and you need to convert this HEX value to byte[16].
Use the following method:

```
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

public static byte[] toByteArray(String s) {
    return DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(s);
}
```

Comment: I have tried this,  but on AES decryption i have got some problems. javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher
 at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:749)
 at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:675)
 at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:313)
 at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2087)